# computed property not displaying correctly in EmberJS, showing [object Object]

Tags: ember.js, towerjs

If I have an ember object in coffeescript as per the documentation

```coffeescript
Person = Ember.Object.extend
  name: null
  lastName: null
  fullName: Ember.computed ->
    return 'hello'
  .property('name', 'lastName')

person = Person.create
  name: 'Tom'
  lastName: 'Tim'
```

Using `person.get('fullName')` returns an ember object instead of the fullname

```coffeescript
m =>
    _cacheable: true
    _dependentKeys: Array[1]
    0: "ownerships"
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
    func: function () {
    __proto__: Ember.Descriptor
```

Because of this (I assume), I see `[object Object]` instead of the fullName

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="personView">
{{#with App.peopleController.person}}
  <dt>First name</dt>
  <dd>{{name}}</dd>
  <dt>Fullname</dt>
  <dd>{{fullName}}</dd>
{{/with}}
</script>
```

This renders:

```
First name
[object Object]
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle ? I don't know towerjs, but it seems that `@get('ownerships').where(hours: ">": 0).count()`return an object (perhaps a relation object)

Comment: I think it'd be difficult to provide a fiddle, but I figured it was coffeescript related, you could be right, I'll check!

Comment: It would appear that it's not that easy, even if I removed that line and say something like `return "hello"` it still shows up as an object. I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointing coffeescript gave me a hint: try to define fullName like this:

```
fullName: (->
   return "hello"
).property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

I think in your example the value returned is the function itself, not the value.

***EDIT***

I tried to translate your code in javascript with: http://tinyurl.com/9mh2eho

Then, paste in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ksRkd/

Both versions seem to work...Perhaps the mistake is somewhere else.

Comment: I'd say it's probably returning the function itself too, because when I do `fullName: 'hello'` instead of the function it correctly returns the right thing, maybe it has to do with the context of the model, I'll have to ask in tower I suspect

Comment: Yep, perhaps with the link I gave, you can translate your code in js, and then create a js fiddle.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm beginning to think this is related to how tower uses getters and setters. I appreciate your help!

Comment: It turns out it was just a matter of syntax. Tower's Model doesn't directly subclass Ember's object, but merely uses it as a proxy, so I had to define the function fullName the same way I would define a property 'name'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fine, I think you can post your solution as an answer, and accept it. It could be usefull to others :)